# I'm trying to use the values inside a .txt file to be able to use it in an equation

Tags: python

I have a `.txt` file which has these values `10,20,30,40,50`. It only has a single row but, with multiple columns. I'm having a hard time on how to use each column as a single value to be used in an equation.

I have the code below:

```py
val = input('Enter the text file name: ')
print('Opening text file: ', val)

try:
    file = open(val + '.txt', 'r').readlines()

    for row in file:
        price_raw = row

except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File name not found.')

price = int(price_raw)
balanceA = 100
balanceB = 100
total_balance = (balanceA + balanceB) * price

print(total_balance)
```

I have tried converting row into an integer but, it prompts

```py
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

I have tried to use `print(type(row))` and the value I am getting from the file is a `string`.

How can I extract all the values in the `.txt` file and use them in the equation for `total_balance`?

For the first column on the `.txt` file, `10`, e.g. `total_balance = (100 + 100) * 10`. Then the next column, which is `20`, e.g. `total_balance = (100 + 100) * 20`

Is it possible for the `total_balance` to contains different values for each of the price value?

How would I approach on doing this?

Comment: You got empty lines in your file - probably behind the last number.

Comment: Your file format is essentially CSV (without headers). Take a look at the *csv* module

Comment: we have no clue how your file looks. Your current code does NOT convert the string to numbers.

Comment: do you have comma `,` separating the values to make the columns in each line of your text file?  that would make it a "comma-separated values" or CSV file. Python has tools for loading CSV files https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: The text file only contains numbers on a single line with comma separating them essentially a csv but on a txt file.

Comment: yes that's a csv file. your current code seems to confuse rows with columns... you say you have a file with one row and columns, so you need to split the row into column values (try just use the csv module though)

Comment: You mention "each row" in your description, but say there's only one row.  Please clarify.  _If_ I understand your format correctly, you can change a single string `s` into a list of strings with `s.split(",")` and then calling `int()` on each of those substrings should work...

Comment: I'm sorry, it was supposed to be "each column" instead of row.

Comment: @DennisManicaniJr., can you confirm if the error you are getting is `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10,20,30,40,50'` or `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`? That is an important detail we need to know to help you better.

Comment: Hello @accdias, yes that was my error when I try to convert the raw values from the txt file to int. I've used **rammelmueller 's** answer and was able to convert it to a list instead of a string. All I need now is a way to use all the values in that list (all 220 values), to my equation above.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I will post a complete answer for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file has exactly one line with the following content:

```
10,20,30,40,50
```

When you:

```
file = open(val + '.txt', 'r').readlines()
```

The variable `file` with end up filled with `['10,20,30,40,50\n']`.

When the loop below ends:

```py
for row in file:
    price_raw = row
```

It will leave `price_raw` set with `'10,20,30,40,50\n'`.

So, when you do:

```py
price = int(price_raw)
```

You are really saying:

```py
price = int('10,20,30,40,50\n')
```

Which is obviously passing an invalid argument to `int()`, hence the error:

```py
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10,20,30,40,50\n'
```

The solution, as pointed by @rammelmueller, is to `split()` the individual columns into single values and then convert each of them to `int()`.

Even though it is not the case here, since you said you have exactly one line per file, it is a good practice to check if the line read is empty, as @PatrickArtner pointed.

With all that in mind, here is a possible solution for your problem:

```py
filename = input('Enter the text file name: ')
print('Opening text file: ', filename)

balanceA = 100
balanceB = 100

try:
    # There are better ways of doing this, I'm leaving it as is just for clarity
    with open(filename + '.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        # Process each line from the file
        for line in lines:
            # We are interested in non empty lines only
            if line.strip():
                # Split the columns and convert them to int()
                prices = [*map(int, line.split(','))]
                # Calculate the total_balance for each price
                for price in prices:
                    total_balance = (balanceA + balanceB) * price
                    print(total_balance)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File name not found.')
```

To completely understand the snippet above, it is recommended that you read the [`map()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), and [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments), to understand the meaning of the `*` in front of the `map()` call.

There is a lot of room for improvements but, I opted to leave the example as close as yours just for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Oh wow that actually worked! I got a single column containing all the values for total_balance and is designated a row for each result. Thank you so much! Sorry for the trouble. I'm only on my 2nd day learning python.

Comment: My pleasure, @DennisManicaniJr. and there's no need to apologize. We all went down that road one day. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily read the line into an array of integers with the following snippet:

```
raw_prices = price_raw.split(",")
prices = list(map(int, raw_prices))
```

Some explanation:

- The `price_raw.split(",")` breaks your input at every "," it finds and returns a list of strings with the numpers.
- The `map` then converts this list to integer.
- Finally, the `list` makes a list from the map object.

Comment: This one-liner doesn't help a newbie to understand. Please split it up and explain what you have done here.

Comment: I tried this inside the `for row in file:` and it printed a lot of number. More than the actual columns in the file itself. lol Did I do anything wrong?
`price_raw = row.split(",")
 price = list(map(int, price_raw))`

Answer (score 1):

### Problem:

Your textfile ends with a `"\n"` - when reading your last line is empty (aka "") - which can not be converted to integer.

```
int("")  # this is what happens in the last line
```

This produces:

=> `Exception has occurred: ValueError, invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

You can not convert empty lines - and need to fix that.

This

> ```
> file = open(val + '.txt', 'r').readlines()
>
> for row in file:
>     price_raw = row
> ```

will open the file and loop through the list of lines of the file - `price_raw` will be reset to hold the value of each single line int turn ... and do nothing with it. The last value of a file content of `10,20,30,40,50\n` will result in `price_raw == ""`.
`int(price_raw) == int("")` => produces your error.

---

### Solutions:

```
# one number per line 
fn = "tata.txt"

with open (fn, "w") as f:
    f.write("10\n")
    f.write("30\n")

try:
    with open(fn) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    # converts all lines that do not strip down to nothing
    # to an integer
    numbers = map(int, (l.strip() for l in lines if l.strip()))


except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

balanceA, balanceB = numbers # decomposition

total_balance = (balanceA+balanceB)*42

print(total_balance)
```

Output:

```
1680
```

If you have multiple values per line, comma separated you need to split(",") each line into single things - see f.e.:

```
# multiple numbers per line - will also work for only a single line
fn = "tata.txt"

with open (fn, "w") as f:
    f.write("10,20\n")    # this will also work for only a single
    f.write("99,120\n")   # line .. 

try:
    with open(fn) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    # converts all lines that do not strip down to nothing
    # to an integer
    lines_with_numbers = [list(map(int, l.split(","))) for l in lines]

except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

for data in lines_with_numbers:

    balanceA, balanceB = data # decomposition

    total_balance = (balanceA+balanceB) * 42
    print("(" , balanceA, "+", balanceB, ") * 42 = ", total_balance)
```

Output:

```
( 10 + 20 ) * 42 =  1260
( 99 + 120 ) * 42 =  9198
```

Comment: Op clearly states they have a CSV file formatted with values in a single row. How a solution based on a value per line helps them?

Comment: @acc The problem is not one or more numbers per line - the problem is the empty line at the end of the file - this code solves that. The splitting of multiple lines with multuiples numbers is edited.

Comment: sorry but my txt file only has a single row which has multiple columns (e.g. 10,20,30,40,50) and I'm trying to obtain the value of each of those columns which I will use on the equation inside my code.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, where, in the question, do you see that information? Again, the author clearly states they have a file with a single line of comma separated values.

Comment: @Dennis - then do not read past your 1 line - or check if the lines you use are empty after .strip()ing them

Comment: @accdias  I see that from `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10.  ''`  which is EXACTLY what happens if you do `int("")` .... and from two gold badges in python, python3 and some 46k reps mainly gathered doing python questions.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, Oh! I see! Just because your +46K reputation, it doesn't mean your answer is right. Be a little more humble, brother man.

Comment: You are adding confusion when creating a file with one value per line and didn't mentioning that is not part of the problem and is just to illustrate your solution. That is a good starting point. Also, you are assuming the input file has empty lines without confirming that with the OP. I'm not arguing against your _Python fu_. I'm arguing about the validity of your answer in this context.

Comment: @accdias - thats where the gold badge comes in. The _error message the OP posted_ matches exactly what the problem is. I'll add a clearer example to humor you, give me a sec.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, you don't need to _humor_ me. Just stick to ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and everyone on SO will be happy.

Comment: @PatrickArtner `total_balance = (balanceA+balanceB) * 42` regarding this line sir, what variable is the 42 from? Is it supposed to be a value from the lines_with_numbers?

Comment: @Dennis it is just that - a number.  If you have more then 2 values per line, you can extract more then 2 values per line - if you have like 3 numbers you can do `a,b,c = data` in the last example. the first value of the line is a, the second b the third c - but that all has nothing to do with your error. Don't handle empty lines. And make sure you do not decomposition more values then you have - `a,b,c = map(int, "22,33".split())` wont work because the resulting map object has only 2 elements that you try to assing into 3 variables.