# How to use all the values of a list and use it in an equation?

Tags: python

I've posted my first question here which is also linked to this question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71707434/im-trying-to-use-the-values-inside-a-txt-file-to-be-able-to-use-it-in-an-equat)

How do I use all the values in a list containing values e.g. [10,20,30,40,50] and use it in an equation?

```
price = [10,20,30,40,50]
total_balance = (balanceA + balanceB) * price
```

I'm hoping it would use each element inside the list as the value for the variable `price` and would result in a list (`total_balance`) that contains the result computed for each element inside that price list using the equation. I've googled questions similar to mine but they only use one value inside the list.

Comment: Where does BalanceA and BalanceB come from? Can you provide a couple example cases done manually to clairify your goal?

Comment: If you want to use all values you need to loop like ```total_balance = [(BalanceA + BalanceB) * p for p in price]``` If the data is very large, then numpy has great solutions. But this is very basic python, so maybe first follow some tutorials.

Comment: BalanceA and BalanceB are declared with values. My only problem is with the `price` since it is a list and it contains 220 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the list:

```
price = [10,20,30,40,50]
total_balance = []
for p in price: # Go through every value in the price list
    tmp_price = (balanceA + balanceB) * p # You calculate the price with the selected value here
    total_balance.append(tmp_price) # Here you add your calculated price to your list with all prices
```

Comment: You can boil this down to one easy to read single line with a list comprehension without unnecessary temp variables.

Comment: @Stefan but clearly OP is very inexperienced. Writing the code this way allows for comments explaining what's going on. That said, I agree with your other comment -- this question doesn't belong on SO as it is currently written.

Comment: @ddejohn I'm sorry. I just learned python two days ago.